# How do I get DVD to play in VLC from unity dash launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, dvd, vlc, unity-dash

Once I put the DVD into DVD drive, it appears in the Unity dash/place. Clicking the icon opens nautilus. How do I make clicking the icon to open VLC player and start playing it ?.

Answer (score 4):

Open Nautilus. Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Media . Select VLC player.

[image]

Comment: I do not have that tab on 12.10.

Comment: Ah, it is in system preferences>system>details. However, this changes what happens upon disk insertion, if I am not mistaken. The original question was about changing the behaviour upon clicking unity launcher (which it does not).

Comment: @sup:if you see, this was for an older version 11.04. Settings and behaviour of nautilus may have changed since then. I will have to check by playing a DVD . :)